# Trying to get property of non-object in: $wp_query

Tags: wp-query, functions

I've this function at `functions.php` file:

```
function custom_secondary_nav( $menu_name, $id = '', $menu_title = '' )
{
    global $wp_query;

    // others stuff goes here   

    if (is_object($wp_query)) {
        $wpQueryObj = get_object_vars($wp_query);
        if (in_array("queried_object", $wpQueryObj)) {
            $query_name =  $wp_query->queried_object->name !== "" ? $wp_query->queried_object->name : "";
        } 
    }
}
```

But all the time I'm getting this PHP Warning:

> PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /var/www/vhosts/elclarinweb.com/httpdocs/sistema/wp-content/themes/elclarin_v2/functions.php
>   on line 86

How I can fix that small issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_object_vars()` returns an *associative array* of object properties - so `queried_object` is never *in* `$wpQueryObj`, it's a key: `$wpQueryObj['queried_object']`.

Besides, you shouldn't be doing any of that anyway - use `get_queried_object()`:

```
if ( $wp_query instanceof WP_Query ) {
    if ( $object = $wp_query->get_queried_object() ) {
         $query_name = isset( $object->name ) ? $object->name : '';
    }
}
```